# Multiples clientes Sockets C#

Tags: c#, socket

Este codigo es del servidor de una aplicacion en C#,por ejemplo tengo 3 clientes conectados,pero no se como hacer si quiero enviarle al primero o al tercero etc etc.

Alguien me de una idea xfa.

```
 private Socket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket; // We will only accept one socket.
    private byte[] buffer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartServer();
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3333));
            serverSocket.Listen(10);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {

        try
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

            // Send a message to the newly connected client.
            var sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
            clientSocket.BeginSend(sendData, 0, sendData.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null); //SendCallback
            // Listen for client data.
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
            // Continue listening for clients.
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {

        try
        {
            clientSocket.EndSend(AR);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            // Socket exception will raise here when client closes, as this sample does not
            // demonstrate graceful disconnects for the sake of simplicity.
            int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);

            if (received == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            // The received data is deserialized in the PersonPackage ctor.
            PersonPackage person = new PersonPackage(buffer);
            SubmitPersonToDataGrid(person);

            // Start receiving data again.
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
        }
        // Avoid Pokemon exception handling in cases like these.
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            ShowErrorDialog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: no usas threads?? cada cliente deberia registrarse...

Comment: Necesitará un servidor multiproceso:
[Http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm](Http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm) Y claro de los clientes:
[Http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-client-socket.htm](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-client-socket.htm)

Comment: @ByronRamirez ¿Ha solucionado el problema?